# How to suppress standard output only for sudo executed at remote host?

Tags: bash, ssh

Now I would like to make a file at a remote server through ssh,
and I would like to change permission by a function

```
function dummy_function() {
  ssh user@domain "touch -p /home/user/test_dir"
  ssh -q -t user@domain "sudo chmod 744 /home/user/test_file"
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "log: success"
  else
    echo "log: failure"
  fi
}
```

Above function is a simplified version and the echo for log is just for example. So please don't care detail.

My problem is prompt generated by sudo is mixed with the log record.

For example, the output above, can be

```
[sudo] password for user:
log: success    # or log: failure
```

I tried

```
ssh -q -t user@domain "sudo --prompt='' chmod 744 /home/user/test_file"
```

It suppressed prompt of sudo but when I failed to input password,
The log message is contaminated,

```
Sorry, try again.
log: success    # or log: failure
```

It seems error message from sudo, Sorry, try again, comes through standard output.
 I would not like to close standard output in case commands following sudo provide some messages through standard output. What should I do to suppress only message from sudo at remote host?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SSH creates a pseudo-tty it combines all the output of the remote commands together into standard output. There is no way to separate them.

You should be able to solve your specific problem by running `sudo` with the `-S` flag to make it use standard error and standard in, instead of the tty directly. Then you can run ssh without a pseudo-tty and you will be able to avoid logging the sudo prompt which will be on standard error. To avoid having your password echoed to the screen when you type you can tie standard in to a `read` command. Something like this should work:

```
ssh -q user@domain "sudo -S chmod 744 /home/user/test_file" < <(read -s && echo $REPLY)
```

Ofcourse, that `read` input redirection will only give you one shot at typing your password correctly before it fails. Also, it won't let any other commands access the standard input. If that's too restrictive, then you might have to do something more complicated, perhaps as an `expect` script.